# Please explain why i am getting the following error when I use itemrenderer and itemeditor components in the datagrid column

Tags: apache-flex

Code:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn id="a" headerText="Notes" dataField="a" width="200" visible="true" editable="false" wordWrap="true" editorDataField="text">

<mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:HBox>
            <mx:Text width="100%" height="100%"/>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemRenderer>
<mx:itemEditor>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:HBox>
            <renderers:EditorTextRenderer width="100%" />
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Component>
</mx:itemEditor>
```

ErrorStackTrace:
ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property text not found on a.mxml.a_inlineComponent3 and there is no default value.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose, your custom component `EditorTextRenderer` should contain property `text`. Or you must set `editorDataField` to that property, which is responsable for editing. For more details read [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_1.html).

*A simple inline item editor contains a single control that supports the data property. Flex automatically copies the current cell data to the item renderer or item editor, and copies the new cell data back to the list control based on the value of the **editorDataField** property*

Comment: I have set editorDataField="text" in the datagridcolumn already

Comment: @flex_novice, yes, I see it. But "text" property must exist in your itemEditor class (EditorTextRenderer in your case).

Comment: Yes, I have set the property "text" in set data overridden method of the custom renderer class. If I use <mx:RichTextEditor> in place of my custom component then also getting same error..

Comment: `<mx:VBox>
  <mx:HBox click="event.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, false))">
   <mx:RadioButton/>
   <mx:Label htmlText="Hello &lt;b>world&lt;/b>"/>
  </mx:HBox>

  <mx:HBox click="event.currentTarget.getChildAt(0).dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, false))">
   <mx:RadioButton/>
   <mx:Label htmlText="&lt;b>Hello&lt;/b> world"/>
 </mx:VBox>`

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't recommend using inline item renderers/editors.  It makes for sloppy code and stops you from reusing the renderers elsewhere (which is kind of the whole point; also, if in separate files it would be easier to debug).  Second, I believe that problem lies in the `EditorTextRenderer` which probably already it's own renderer and doesn't support the 'text' attribute.  I think what you want to do is this:

```
<mx:itemEditor>
<renderers:EditorTextRenderer width="100%" />
   </mx:itemEditor>
```

Comment: @JAX Please give an idea how to resolve this issue. What would be your approach in this case